# How to turn off VS Code auto-formatting for Markdown files?

Tags: markdown, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to exclude my Readme.md file from auto-formatting when saving in VS Code? I still want auto-format for other file types.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Go to settings.json and paste:

```
"[markdown]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false,
  }
```

[Here is the link, where you find this and other configurations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_languagespecific-editor-settings)